# Drupal 8 missing filter view schema

Tags: views

After run unit tests i am getting fail

```
Schema errors for views.view.example_form_element with the following errors: views.view.example_form_element:display.default.display_options.filters.my_module.expose.example_element missing schema
```

I understand the error but i can't solve it. I tried a lot of combinations of schema.yml file name and content but without success result.

I will point out, that module name is

> my_modules

but

> example_element

is under

> my_module

current file looks like

## file config/schema/my_modules.views.schema.yml

```
views.filter.views_example_element:
  type: views_filter
  label: 'xxx'
  mapping:
    expose:
      type: mapping
      label: 'Exposed'
      mapping:
        example_element:
          type: integer
          label: 'xxx'
```

## file Plugin/views/filter/ViewsExampleElement

```
@ViewsFilter("views_example_element")
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try change in `my_modules.views.schema.yml` `type` on `views.filter.many_to_one`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Of course i rebuild cache after each iteration.

Comment: can this option work for you [custom-views-filter](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-filter-drupal-8)?

Comment: I read this article before and comments bellow containing informations about schema, but without success, so after many tries i decided to wrote this topic to get an solution dedicated for me, because i am stuck without any ideas...